# Can we check activity logs in azure kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, monitoring

I have created one k8s cluster on Azure. I want to see other users activity logs like who created service account, pods or other resources. Is it possible get such activity logs in k8s cluster?

Comment: i think `kubectl get events` is your best bet, or a custom controller

Comment: Kubectl get events gives information about pod events like fetching image , node assignment etc but i am interested in who created which resource inside cluster.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/ ?

Comment: Any update? Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: When i checked on AKS update page, i found that control plane audit logs are still in active development [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/aks-control-plane-audit-logs/)